# Moderators are no longer able to see the privilege other users have

Tags: support, moderator-tools, privileges

When I watch a user profile on Drupal Answers, as moderator I get also a *privileges* link.

> [image: screenshot]

Differently from the past, that link takes me to `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges`, which shows my privileges.

Comment: This power was probably a glitch to begin with; there is no point in making the comparison of public numbers moderator-only.

Comment: I don't see the point of making this moderators-only; I agree on that. I still would like to see privileges users have for when I am answering to questions about something users are expecting to be able to do/see, when this is possible because privileges.

Comment: This is occasionally useful for support purposes, @badp. In particular when privilege levels change.

Comment: @Shog9 True, but it could very well be something anybody can do.

Comment: Anyone *can* do it - [the actual page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/user/13992) isn't protected, @badp. It's just not linked to anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This information is still available - you just need to access it via the mod menu:

[image: mod->info->privileges]

Comment: Greatest fears and Favorite colors are CM only, I presume?

Comment: As long as CM doesn't stand for Cenobite Monster, sure.

Comment: If info on bits of string fell into the wrong hands...

Comment: This is to hide the actual abilities Diamond mods have?

Comment: That and amuse myself, @Ben. Mostly the latter.